# Pig: Invalid field Projection; Projected Field does not exist

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

```
describe filter_records;
```

This gives me the below format:

```
filter_records: {details1: (firstname: chararray,lastname: chararray,age: int,gender: chararray),details2: (firstname: chararray,lastname: chararray,age: int,gender: chararray)}
```

I want to display the `firstname` from both `details1` and `details2`. I tried this:

```
display_records = FOREACH filter_records GENERATE display1.firstname;
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Invalid field projection. Projected field [display1] does not exist in schema: details1:tuple(firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray),details2:tuple(firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray).
```

Please suggest why this error and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see any relation name `display1` in the `filter_records`.  I guess instead of `details1.firstname` you used  `display1.firstname`. Can you change your script like this?

```
display_records = FOREACH filter_records GENERATE details1.firstname;
```

It seems you used same variable names(firstname, lastname,age,gender) in both details1 and details2. It will give duplicate error when you print like this

```
display_records = FOREACH filter_records GENERATE details1.firstname,details2.firstname;
```

To solve this issue you need to provide a unique names in the details1 and details2 relation, Can you change your load schema like this? or you can give any unique name in the details1 and details2.

```
details1:tuple(firstname1:chararray,lastname1:chararray,age1:int,sex1:chararray),details2:tuple(firstname2:chararray,lastname2:chararray,age2:int,sex2:chararray)
```

Now when you try like this, you will get the firstname from details1 and details2

```
display_records = FOREACH filter_records GENERATE details1.firstname1,details2.firstname2;
```